# What happens to a lead acid battery capacity as its temperature increases while discharge current is the same?

Tags: battery-charging

I know that storing a battery at a lower temperature will reduce the chemical reaction, thus retaining the battery capacity for a longer shelf life.

For a battery in use a higher temperature will result in a battery being able to deliver more amp hours due to making the chemical reaction more efficient.

But, it also results in lowering the life of the battery due to increased hydrogen gas production, increased rate of electrolyte solution evaporation.

However, if the discharge current is kept the same while the temperature is increased, then, the Ah of the battery will increase!

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical lead acid battery is manufactured by using lead plates as the poles in electrolyte liquid. This liquid sulfuric acid creates an electro-chemical reaction that will produce a charge on the battery plates which are connected to the terminals.   The warmer the batter the faster the internal chemical activity will be. It is able to put out more energy. In the northern climates it is very common to turn the head lights on for a minute or so before starting the vehicle. Some even use battery heaters. Note: The warmer the battery the faster the internal corrosion within the cells this reduces the lifespan of your battery.